# objects being replaced with latest one

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I have a class called users that takes in parameters for initializing a new user by the constructor like ID , Name , last name, password and and a integer value for permission

```
Users temp1 = new Users("id1","name1","lname","pass1",0);
Users temp2 = new Users("id2","name1","lname","pass2",0);
Users temp3 = new Users("id3","name1","lname","pass3",0);
```

Then I add them to a list that keeps track off all the users currently created like :

```
datastorage.adduser(temp1);
datastorage.adduser(temp2);
datastorage.adduser(temp3);
```

My class for datastorage looks like this :

```
public class datastorage {
 static ArrayList<Users> userlist = new ArrayList<Users>();
    }

    public static void adduser(Users temp){


            userlist.add(temp);

    for (Users user : userlist) {
          System.out.println(user.getuserName() + " "+ user.getPassword());

    }


}
```

when i run the adduser method i wanted to check to see in console all the current users i have in listofusers after adding a new user but instead of printing out :

```
id1 pass1
id2 pass2
id3 pass3
```

I'm not getting something like :

```
id1 pass1
id1 pass1
id2 pass2
id1 pass1
id2 pass2
id3 pass3
```

Comment: That's the actual code for creating `temp` users?

Comment: Is there any reason you make things `static`?

Comment: `Users` class implementation, please.

Comment: sure one second editing OP to add users class

Comment: If you also made the fields and methods static inside the class Users, then the bahvior could be considered as expected.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran you hit `nice edit` :) . I have confused about *im getting*

Comment: You out put is wrong, because, for a single user addition, you are printing whole list. So the expected output is wrong

Comment: Thank you @Seleenvirtuose

turns out the problem was not due to the array-list and how i was adding it rather because the implementation of methods and fields were set to static.

Removed the static and it worked thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the fields in your `Users` class shouldn't be `static`.
They are linked to **instances** of `Users`, while **static** fields are linked to the class itself.

Thus, you actually only have ***ONE*** field (well, one for `userId`, one for `userName` etc.) that is shared among all instances of `Users`.

Just get rid of those `static` modifiers and you should be good. I would still suggest you to read [this tutorial about class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), it would really help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There surely must be some problem with the Users class you defined.May be its been declared static and so the latest temp3 is updated for all the instances of Users namely temp1,temp2,temp3